# c++ programming reference (Stroustrup) - differences between 3rd and 4th edition

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to improve my C++ knowledge and I've been thinking of buying "The C++ Programming Reference (Stroustrup)".

I don't expect I will be writing a huge amount of C++ code, and will probably only write C++ 11 when I do.  I can pick up a copy of the 3rd edition of the book much cheaper than the 4th edition.  I'm thinking of buying the 3rd edition now, and buying the 4th edition some point in the future.

How much has changed in C++ 11 - is reading the 3rd edition before the 4th going to be a waste of time?

Can answers please try to include a quantitative appraisal of the differences between in the C++ versions represented by the 3rd and 4th edition from a C++ newbies perspective?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask this question. However, I'd wait a few more days for the new revision, C++11 brings quite a lot of features to the table. I think the standard grew from about 800 to about 1200 pages.

Comment: C++11 introduces some stuff that can really change the style you code. Some say it feels like a new language.

Comment: just an idea http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus11-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer , but I should also say that the standard from is pretty readable too, it feels more like a manual, more "dry", but I think that reading the standard can be a good thing to start with the right foot.

Comment: C++ is a slow language to learn, and since C++11 even more so, by the time a well advancing newbie gets into it C++14 will already be out with a load of new features.

Comment: @ddriver: ddriver: Are you suggesting to jump in with C++ 14?

Comment: "Holders" - I've reworded the question, is it more appropriate now?

Comment: @Chris - no, not really. Historically, C++ has been a language slow to change, which is one of the reasons I like it, because you can learn it and get proficient instead of playing the perpetual catching up with frequent release cycles. If you ask me, C++14 is pretty much all long overdue core additions and new tools to solve old problems with extra language features for the user to use, rather than solve the problems internally.

Comment: @Chris: Even if you get to a purely non-opinion-based question, it's still about a book recomendation. This site is about problems you face while programming, so this question is off topic anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very probably a waste of money to buy the 3rd edition, as C++ 11 is very different in spirit from the versions before. At least, you should know what the new features are, and you cannot learn about that from an old book.

If you have the possibility to use C++ 11, then do it -- the programming time you save will pay for any book.

Comment: Note that the 4th edition seems to contain a lot of typos. This is a real problem.

Comment: Stroustrup updates his books in short cycles with each printing. When buying used be sure to check to printing number.